# Oracle syslog auditing - no UPDATE messages on syslog server

Tags: oracle, syslog, audit

Oracle is configured to send syslog messages to syslog server. All syslog messages are received except UPDATE and INSERT statements. These statements (with all other) are logged inside database and can be viewed inside UNIFIED_AUDIT trail view. For UPDATE/INSERT, we can see exact AUDIT_POLICY which triggered audit (inside db) but that alert is not shipped via syslog. All others are... We used tcpdump on syslog server to examine payload.

Any other ideas what could be issue? Oracle version is  19c.

Regards,

Comment: *Oracle is configured to send syslog messages to syslog server."* How did you do that configuration? Also, which OS are you running on?

Comment: Regarding configuration, editing of init${ORACLE_SID}.ora                                                file where we have following:

`*.audit_syslog_level='USER.DEBUG'
*.audit_trail='OS'`

Then, inside rsyslog.conf, we added :

`user.debug      @<syslog_server_address>`

Regarding OS, it is AIX 7.1